# Arduino to Serial Cable Encoding Error

Tags: arduino, serial, communication

I am trying to send data between an Arduino Uno and a Mac.

The Arduino Uno is running this simple sketch to print data to serial:

```
int redButtonState = 0;
int redButton = 4;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(19200, SERIAL_8N1);
}

void loop() {
 redButtonState = digitalRead(redButton);
 String x = "Hello";
 if (redButtonState == LOW) {
  Serial.print(x);
  delay(1000);
   }
}
```

I have a USB to Serial Cable plugged into the Mac. The Serial Cable Tx and Rx are connected to the Tx and RX on the Arduino Uno.

I expect to see "Hello" in Cool Term, instead I get this:

[image: image of Cool Term]

I have also tried goSerial with Similar results, both were setup to 19200, 8 data bits, no parity and 1 stop bits.

Comment: "The Serial Cable Tx and Rx are connected to the Tx and RX on the Arduino Uno." - Have you tried the other way round: TX<->RX and RX<->TX?

Comment: @HannoBinder yup, in that instance there is no output.

Comment: Do you receive the same three values each time, or do they change from one attempt to the next?

Comment: @HannoBinder same values each time, which leads me to believe (but I might be wrong) that it's some kind of encoding error.

Comment: Do you have the µC's correct main clock frequency (f_cpu) configured for your program? - Otherwise the bitrates will be wrong.

Comment: @HannoBinder I'm not sure what you mean. Besides the baud rate, data bits, parity and stop bits. What else would I need to configure?

Comment: Because the µC generates the bit rate for the USART from its main clock the frequency of the CPU clock needs to be specified when building your program. - I'm not very Arduino-savvy but maybe have a look at the [Build Process](http://arduino.cc/en/Hacking/BuildProcess) and its parameters.

Comment: You have "RTS" highlighted in your window which part of the handshaking procedure when using RS232 I think. Shouldn't you just be using straight up serial TX/RX since your USB-to-serial converter takes care of all of the necessary conversions?

Comment: Thomas is right that you won't want to use a normal USB serial cable but rather a logic level one.  However, why are you using an adapter cable at all?  The Uno has that functionality built in.  Try just using the serial monitor in the Arduino software right after you load your sketch.  Or connect your other program to the /dev/cu.usbmodemxxxx device created when you plug it in.